# Two objects fly away whenever exported as .fbx

Tags: mesh, armature, export, .fbx, pose-mode

[image]

Hello! I have an issue where the two highlighted meshes don't retain their position when exported as .fbx. I have tried applying transformation, rotation, and scale as suggested in another question, but this doesn't seem to fix the issue.

[image]

For reference, they should be controlled by the Head bone, which they appear to be in Pose view at least. I did notice that the objects themselves seem to have empty space, but I can't seem to find any geometry present and centering doesn't seem to help.

[image]

I had been using this tutorial (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DMpQ_dAzevI) to combine the meshes and armatures before, but no luck this time

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the answer for me was "use Blender 2.79 instead of Blender 3.4" which showed me the true position of the objects I was manipulating.